# I have to convert below SQL Query to informatica cloud logic

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

Out put of joiner transformation(TestData table name in SQL Query) as below

[image]

I need to load data in to target as below

[image]

I wrote SQL Query like

SELECT * FROM TestData AS A
WHERE SourceSystem = 'NC'  AND
EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM TestData AS B
WHERE B.ClusterID = A.ClusterID AND B.SourceString = '50012559'
AND B.SourceSystem = 'ACB'
)

can you help me how to covert this SQL Query to Informatica cloud .

Comment: Have you actually tried your current query on Informatica?  I expect it will work.

Comment: Yes, you can convert this to infa cloud mapping. But i think your sql isnt going to work because there is no data for `B.SourceSystem = 'ACBS'`. What is the logic you want to implement?

Comment: @koushik Roy Sorry for typo that is ACBS=ABC .

Comment: @Tim how can I put query after joiner, can you please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `testData` is a joiner output here is the solution. I assumed, cluster id is the unique key. if it not unique key, then this solution will cause duplicates.

First, sort your joiner output `TestData` by ClusterID.

Then put a filter(filter1) on SourceSystem = 'NC' and create pipeline 1.
Connect another filter(filter2) to sorter on SourceString = '50012559' AND B.SourceSystem = 'ACB' and create pipeline 2.
Add another joiner - conditions will be pipeline1.ClusterID =pipeline2.ClusterID.

The output from joiner will be your desired data.

This is how the mapping would look like -

```
                                    |-Filter 1 ->|  
TestData_Joiner... -SRT_ClusterID-->|-Filter 2 ->| -JNR_ClusterID-> <desired output>
```

Pls note, this will generate data just like below SQL.
``
SELECT * FROM TestData AS A WHERE SourceSystem = 'NC' AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TestData AS B WHERE B.ClusterID = A.ClusterID AND B.SourceString = '50012559' AND B.SourceSystem = 'ACB' )

Comment: Thank you Koushik! Here , test data is after joiner transformation output, from there I have to implement same logic. I can't take this TestData in Source qualifier .

Comment: i will modify keeping in mind `Testdata` is a joiner output

Comment: Thank you Koushik!! It is working fine. Another way I also implemented using expression variable ports by assigning loan number to all records and next filtered only NC records. both approaches are working as accepted. than you again.